# Is it possible to get/delete job in RabbitMQ queue by some job ID or details inside the job?

Tags: rabbitmq

I have RabbitMQ server running and some queues with some jobs.

I want to call RabbitMQ and get a job by ID to check if it's in the queue, is it possible? Delete by some filter? How? Can't find docs.

e.g. job = `{user: 1, action: 'justDoIt', options: {useBranding: false}}`

and I want to delete/get all jobs where `user === 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot browse/filter the queues.

you can consume the messages check them and re-queue (if you need)

Comment: Thanks for confirming this